# New Install Problem (TeXShop)

Tags: xetex, installing, code

I just bought a new Mac.  So I downloaded *TeXShop* and tried to typeset a test file.  I got this error:

> xelatex: Command not found.

Is there something wrong with in my preface? Yes, I'm sure there's a bunch of things wrong in my preface (I can get corrections to those later). But right now, specifically, is there something wrong in my preface that would keep TeXShop from typesetting?  On my previous Mac, it has the same version of TeXShop running on it. And it typeset just fine.  I'm wondering what might be wrong.

Here's my test file:

> %!TEX TS-program = xelatex %!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
>
> \documentclass[12pt,landscape]{article}
>
> \usepackage{lettrine} \usepackage{fancyhdr} \usepackage{setspace}
> \usepackage{fancybox}
>
> \usepackage{tabulary} \setlength\tymin{100pt}
> \setlength\tymax{\maxdimen}
>
> \usepackage[xetex, %colorlinks=true,
> pdfstartview=FitH]{hyperref}
>
> \usepackage{xltxtra}
>
> \usepackage{geometry}                  %\geometry{letterpaper}
> %\geometry{landscape} %\geometry{twocolumn}
> %%\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}     %\usepackage{graphicx}
> %\usepackage{amssymb}
>
> \usepackage{xunicode}
>
> \usepackage{fontspec} \input{bidi.tex}
>
> \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Minion Pro Medium}
> %\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{GFS Neohellenic}
> \setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Myriad Pro}
>
> \setmonofont{Courier}
> \newfontfamily{\ezr}[Script=Hebrew,Scale=1.5]{SBL Hebrew}
> \newfontfamily{\por}[Script=Greek]{Minion Pro Display}
> \newfontfamily{\ath}[Script=Coptic]{Accordance}
> %\newfontfamily{\ath}[Script=Coptic,Scale=1.1]{Antinoou}
>
> \newfontfamily{\scripture}{Minion Pro Cond Italic Display}  %SLANTED
> TEXT \newfontfamily{\preface}{Minion Pro Semibold Cond Display}
> \newfontfamily{\cite}[Script=Latin,Scale=.9]{Minion Pro Cond Display}
> \newfontfamily{\ger}[Script=Latin]{1517 Gilgengart}
> \newfontfamily{\app}[Script=Latin]{0425 Uncialis Romana}
> %\newfontfamily{\syr}[Script=Latin,Scale=1.5]{Peshitta}
>
> \newfontfamily{\syr}[Script=Syriac,Scale=1.3]{Accordance}
>
> %INCLUDE when using MARGINAL NOTES %\setlength{\marginparsep}{0.3in}
>
> \geometry{verbose,letterpaper,tmargin=0.8in,bmargin=0.8in,lmargin=0.8in,rmargin=0.8in,headheight=0.5in,headsep=0.2in,footskip=1.0
> in}
>
> % text for headers and footers \pagestyle{fancy} \lhead{{\scriptsize
> John 2:1-11;   Sun, Jan 20\textsuperscript{th}, 2020} }
> \chead{{\scriptsize \href{http://stevebauer.us}{Pastor Steve Bauer} }
> } \rhead{{\scriptsize \href{http://www.immanuelgibbon.org}{Immanuel
> Lutheran Church}} }
>
> \usepackage{bigfoot}
>
> \DeclareNewFootnote[para]{default} \DeclareNewFootnote[para]{B}[alph]
> \MakeSortedPerPage{footnoteB}
>
> \newcounter{footalt} \def\thefootalt{\fnsymbol{footalt}}
> \MakeSortedPerPage[2]{footalt}
> \WithSuffix\def\footnotedefault’{\refstepcounter{footalt}%
> \Footnotedefault{\thefootalt}}
>
> \renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{-3pt}% \hrule width 1.5in height
> 0.4pt \vspace{2.6pt}}
>
> \usepackage{multicol} \setlength{\columnsep}{.7 cm}
>
> \begin{document} \begin{multicols*}{2}
>
> \section*{}    \lettrine{WORDS}{WORDS}
>
> \end{multicols*}
>
> \end{document}

Finally, I ask for your patience. I have been using Tex for decades now. But I haven't done much on the coding side of things for many years. So I'm beyond rusty.

Comment: You need to install also MacTeX

Comment: and after you have installed mactex you should start with a small hello world example and not with a document that loads tons of packages and needs local fonts. Btw: xunicode and xltxtra are obsolete.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers.  I have it up and running now.  How do I mark this as answered?